# Two drivers missing (with exclamation mark) on fresh Windows 10 install on a Sony Vaio VPCCA2S0E

Tags: windows-10, drivers, sony-vaio, memory-card

A fresh install of Windows 10 on a Sony Vaio VPCCA2S0E laptop leaves two undefined devices with exclamation marks in Device Manager. The first listed as an LPC Interface controller and the second with only the Hardware ID ACPI\SNY5001 to help.

Updating the drivers via windows update and searching the Sony Vaio Support & Downloads sites were not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answers turned out to by the `Ricoh PCIe Memory Stick Host Controller` version `6.21.11.30` driver that I found on the [Microsoft Update Catalog](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=Ricoh%20PCIe%20Memory%20Stick%20Host%20Controller) after finding an earlier version on a Sony update site. (It seems similar symptoms can arise from Realtek memory card controllers.)

And the `Sony Firmware Extensible Parser Device` version `8.0.1.1` that I found on the [Microsoft Update Catalog](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=Sony%20Firmware%20Extension%20Parser).

I hope this information spares others the blind alleys I went down. The Sony web sites and the installers they offer can be actively unhelpful.

Comment: Yeah, sony support for drivers sucks.